# ReferenceError: window is not defined during vue-cli 3 build

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2

A pretty long time ago I created a project using `vue create`. After several months of development, we decided to **not** support IE11 or any versions below that (yay!).

To do this, I want to add **pure Javascript code** to `index.html` inside the `public` folder.

I added the following to `index.html`:

```js
<script>
  if (window.document.documentMode) {
    setDisplay('app', 'none');
    setDisplay('browser-not-supported', 'block');
  }

  function setDisplay(elId, display) {
    var element = window.document.getElementById(elId);

    if (!element) {
      return;
    }

    element.style.display = display;
  }
</script>
```

However, running `yarn build:production` again, I get the following error:

```
Template execution failed: ReferenceError: window is not defined

  ReferenceError: window is not defined

  - index.html:98
    /Users/[username]/Development/[...]/public/index.html:98:10

  - index.html:105 0971.module.exports
    /Users/[username]/Development/[...]/public/index.html:105:3

  - index.js:284 Promise.resolve.then
    [projectname]/[html-webpack-plugin]/index.js:284:18
```

I already added `configureWebpack: config => { config.output.globalObject = 'this' }` to `vue.config.js`, according to another answer on SO.
I also set `env: { node: true, browser: true }` in `.eslintrc.js`.

It doesn't matter if I put the code in the `head` or `body`, same error occurs.

Is there anything I can check, or anything I missed here?

Comment: Would a simple window check solve this? `var element = !!window ? window.document.getElementById(elId) : null;` Not familiar with Vue's build process, but is it possible window is not available, since it's not happening in the browser?

Comment: I did that! I switched between a variety of checks, but every single time it would say "window is not defined". Even when I do something like `let windowHandle = window ? window : {}` or a few variations thereof. It's maddening! I think it's semantically / statically checking the file or something. Also that it says "Template execution failed" makes me wonder. Thank you for your input, though! Window is definitely not available in `node`, in which it is compiling, so that was my first thought: checking for `window`. It does not matter :(

Comment: Why not do this in Vue entry point? This is what it's for. I would expect it to work in legacy browsers. There's no place for trial and error. Webpack obviously evaluates inline script with Node, this is the only reason why `window` can be undefined. At this point this is purely JS problem. As with any other potentially nonexistend global, a safeguard should be `if (typeof window !== 'undefined' && window) ...`, not `window ? window : {}` (it chokes on first `window`).

Comment: @EstusFlask putting your example (`if (typof ...`) emits the same error. For some reason (even with .browserslistrc), IE11 emits a lot of errors, which is why I wanted to put it before any application code, hence why I put it in index.html. I also would love to NOT use babel to compile everything to IE11-compatible code, because we don't support it. Otherwise, what's the point?

Comment: I expect `typeof` to work. Double check that you don't mention `window` outside of the condition and check line numbers that are provided for index.html. The point is that there's a bunch of not so old browsers besides IE that don't support *all* ES features, and since you need a build step with Vue any way, why not use Babel? I meant that main.js should contain `if (isIE) { ... } else { new Vue(...) }`. If you don't use exotic packages that aren't ES5-ready and thus fail on `import`, this should work.

Comment: The _very_ first mention of `window` is in the `typeof` check now. Same error. Line numbers don't match up, probably because of the build process. I use Doka in the main.js file, which is probably why the app won't boot at all when putting this code in main.js. Even when I extract Doka's code from node_modules, put it in `libs/` and push it through the Babel process, it gives the exact same problems. Everything you say I already tried, unfortunately. I want to know why I can't use this code in index.html, along with where to put the code in the best scenario (main.js obviously).